# Powershell - forward slash inside string

Tags: powershell, escaping

As far as I know the forward slash isn't a special character in PowerShell, but in this particular situation the forward slash causes a problem.

```
Write-Host $([DateTime]::Now.ToString("MM/dd yyyy"))
```

In this case `ToString` ignores the custom date format (probably because it can't parse it) and outputs date in the default format.

I know how to solve the problem - I can escape the forward slash with a backward slash `"MM\/dd yyyy"`, but I'd like to know why it is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not PowerShell doing it, but the .Net framework. / in a date format is seen as the [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) and will be replaced with the date separator set in the Windows settings. The escape for that is a backslash as you noticed.

```
Write-Host $([DateTime]::Now.ToString("MM\/dd yyyy"))
```