# PowerShell AWS command: Unknown token /

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run this command;

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=22 Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=22 --query 'SecurityGroups[?((IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0") || (IpPermissions.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6 == "::/0"))].[GroupId]' --profile "prod" --region "us-east-1" | out-file $output -Encoding ASCII -append
```

It throws me the following error;
Unknown token /: (It seems like PowerShell doesn't like "/" )

```
Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?((IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp == 0.0.0.0/0) || (IpPermissions.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6 == ::/0))].[GroupId]: Bad jmespath 
expression: Unknown token /:
SecurityGroups[?((IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp == 0.0.0.0/0) || (IpPermissions.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6 == ::/0))].[GroupId]
```

*How can I write the command and tell PowerShell that the slash is just a slash and to run it?*

Thank you!

The code to run and list all security groups that have public IP addresses.

Comment: Would this be a relevant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429046/powershell-forward-slash-inside-string

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a backslash as an escape character:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=22 Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=22 --query 'SecurityGroups[?((IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0\/0") || (IpPermissions.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6 == "::\/0"))].[GroupId]' --profile "prod" --region "us-east-1" | out-file $output -Encoding ASCII -append
```

Comment: Same error. Thank you for the input, though.

Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?((IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp == 0.0.0.0\/0) || (IpPermissions.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6 == ::\/0))].[GroupId]: Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token \:
SecurityGroups[?((IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp == 0.0.0.0\/0) || (IpPermissions.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6 == ::\/0))].[GroupId]